# How to make a condition in where clause as void

Tags: postgresql

I have a function in Postgresql where we have a parameter uuid[]. I basically have 2 requirements.

1. uuid[] I would like to make it as optional
2. In the where clause if uuid[] is null or not passed then the condition I would like to make it as void something similar to COALESCE.

I tried the below function for my requirement . For setting it as optional I have set it as default null and in the where clause used COALESCE. However it throws error saying syntax error at or near "ANY"

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION riello.spgetuserinvitations( 
    p_useremail character varying,
    p_homeids uuid[] default null)
    RETURNS TABLE(invitationid uuid) 
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    COST 100
    VOLATILE PARALLEL UNSAFE
    ROWS 1000

AS $BODY$
#variable_conflict use_column

<<fnp>>
DECLARE
    v_exmsg VARCHAR(1000);  
BEGIN  
    
    RETURN QUERY
SELECT
  *
FROM table  
WHERE (useremail) = (p_useremail)
    AND invh.homeid = COALESCE(ANY(p_homeIds),invh.homeid)    

  EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
                    GET STACKED DIAGNOSTICS fnp.v_errorstate = RETURNED_SQLSTATE,
                        fnp.v_errormsg = MESSAGE_TEXT;
                    fnp.v_exmsg := COALESCE(fnp.v_errormsg, 'Unknown Error');
                    RAISE EXCEPTION 'Error %, severity %, state % was raised. Message: %.', '50000', 14, -1, fnp.v_exmsg USING ERRCODE = fnp.v_errorstate;
END fnp;
$BODY$;

ALTER FUNCTION riello.spgetuserinvitations(character varying, uuid[])
    OWNER TO adminuser;
```